# My borders don't collapse in pandas styler

Tags: css, pandas, html-table, format, pandas-styles

A function that defines the layout of a dataframe. All is well, except I need my borders to collapse. I have tried everything. I need NO borders in my headers(col headers and index) but need a collapsed small grey border in my cells. Strangely enough I also have white borders in my headers even though I did not define that.

`

```
def style_df(df_):
    def style_negative(v, props=''):
        return props if v < 0 else None
    
    cell_hover = {
    "selector": "td:hover",
    "props": [("background-color", "#7FB3D5")]
    }
    index_names = {
    "selector": ".index_name",
    "props": "font-style: italic; color: white"
    }
    headers = {
    "selector": "th",
    "props": "background-color: #273746; color: white;font-size: 12px;font-family: sans-serif"
    }
    cells = {
    "selector": "td",
    "props": "background-color: white; font-size: 12px;font-family: sans-serif;border:1px solid #707B7C;border-collapse:collapse"
    }  
    x=df_.style\
        .applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;')\
        .format(formatter='{:,.2f}%',na_rep='-')\
        .set_table_styles([cell_hover,index_names, headers,cells])
    return x          




df_dict={"col1":np.random.random(10),"col2":np.random.random(10)}
df_random=pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df_random
style_df(df_random)
```

`

I tried border-collapse:collapse in only td and th or only in table. Nothing works.

Comment: `border-collapse` is a table level CSS value, it should not be applied to `td` or `th` cells. see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.php

Answer (score 1):

This is my view after adjusting for the answer of Sergey. Still white space between cells.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = {
"selector": "th",
"props": "background-color: #273746; color: white"
}
cells = {
"selector": "td",
"props": "background-color: white; font-size: 12px;font-family: sans-serif;border:1px solid #707B7C;border-collapse:collapse; border: 0.5px solid"
}
```

Output:

[image]

p.s. the white border for the header is specified in your header, see this example, how it works:

```
headers = {
    "selector": "th",
    "props": "background-color: #273746; color: green;font-size: 12px;font-family: sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;  border: solid"
    }
cells = {
    "selector": "td",
    "props": "background-color: white; font-size: 12px;font-family: sans-serif;border:1px solid #707B7C;border-collapse:collapse; border: 0.5px solid"
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks. I see how it works. But the strangest thing happens in my notebook. If I copy your answer: still white spaces in my header. If I try your code with the green: it addas green borders indeed in my header but next to that I still have white space line between header cells. Also white space between all cells

Comment: this the styling I got from my notebook directly.  Is that the problem with the notebook set up?

Comment: Hmm using Jupiter lab. Nothing to setup.

Comment: I use ipykernel